# Count the number of times a date occurred in a report

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to Count the amount of times a date comes up in an excel report.

The data in my report shows as follows:

> 7/7/2014 13:56
>   7/7/2014 11:26
>   7/7/2014 10:48
>   7/7/2014 9:57
>   7/4/2014 11:49

I need to create a formula to do this automatically, I just want to pass the report in the DATA sheet and have the formula discriminate the amount of times each date comes up.

I haven't been able to figure it out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would you like the use of Pivot tables? They are the easiest way to generate reports. Line in your case - finding out "how many times the data is repeated" for example...

Comment: I download a report from one of our tools that shows all the evaluations done in a month, the line that shows the date has the following format : 7/7/2014 13:56. I need to count how many evaluations were done in each day.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample worksheet and uploaded to this location. See if this is what you need.

Here is how it works:
1. From your tool output which is a combination of date and time, we will extract the date and time in two separate columns. The pre-requisite for doing this to define the column (which is the tool output) as "text" type. Right click-> Format cells-> select "Text" as type.
2. The extraction of date and time is done by "left" command and "mid" command respectively.
3. After the date and type are available in two different columns, just use pivot table and generate the report you want. (in your case the number of times a particular day has occurred) 
I hope this helps!

[date.xlsx - Sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-6XDkJiElCba1RIbUt3aWxkNE0/edit?usp=sharing)